# Print the current stack trace in ClojureScript?

Tags: stack-trace, clojurescript

I'm debugging a ClojureScript program and I want to know where this function is called from, but I don't want to interrupt its execution. I already have source maps working. How do I print the current stack trace to console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the JavaScript [Console API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace).

```
(.trace js/console)
```

In most browsers, it gives nice traces with source file links.

[clojure.stacktrace/print-stack-trace](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.stacktrace/print-stack-trace) is undefined in CLJS.